# Is my WCF using the correct Binding?

Tags: wcf, binding, web-config

My wcf service's web.config looks like this:

How can I confirm that it is using the settings correctly?

**I still get this timeout error sometimes even though I have configured the binding to use:
 SendTimeout = 10 minutes etc. ?**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyServiceBehavior"
        name="MyService.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="longTimeoutBinding"
          bindingName="" contract="MyService.IMyService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="longTimeoutBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="1048576" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyService.MyServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My client (windows service) app.config looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="1048576" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://local/MyService/MyService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"
        contract="MyService.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: "I still get this timeout error sometimes..."  Which timeout error?  What exactly is happening when you try to connect?  Do you own the client?

Comment: i own the client yes.  My error logs are showing an error message like: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00 ...

Comment: Please post your client configuration as well.

Comment: Terry, I posted the client config also.  Looks like I need to change the settings there....

Comment: Yeah - try that and then if it works, let us know with an answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you set the sendTimeout in the client to 10 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the timeout values in the client side config.